# Как разместить знак в конце елемента списка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

[image: Список]

Как сделать стрелки в конце строки списка?

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с позиционированием стрелки с помощью псевдоэлемента

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}

.list li+li {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 35px 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list a:before {
  content: 'i';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.list a:hover {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">List text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List text text text text text text text text text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List text</a></li>
</ul>
```